# How to set the height of an item row in GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

[image: Current View is]

My Recycler Item which inflate in onCreateViewHolder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gridListImageView"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gridListView_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[I want to display something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBhnL.png)
Which has one row of half the height of recycler View?
And add padding to the rest of the space?
Can i do this by GridLayoutManager?

And this is my GridLayoutManager

```
        GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
```

Comment: If you set a specific height for your `RecyclerView`, you could just set half of that as height for the `LinearLayout`. If not, for example if you want one item to be half of the screen height, you have to do it programmatically, get the screen height, do some calculations and set the LayoutParams.

Comment: you have to calculate the screen height- minus nav bar height and then divide it by 2 to get height of a row

Comment: why dont you try with LinearLayout, will be easy with using weightSum

Comment: @AmitVaghela I have to add more items so i have to use recycler view!

Comment: @Amy, I'm getting view.getLayoutParams().height as -1
and view.getMeasuredHeight() as 0. 
What to do?

Comment: When inflating layout for your views in adapter, you can set their height programmatically. In order to evaluate proper height to use you can rely on parent ViewGroup (that is the RecyclerView itself). [Here](https://github.com/thetonrifles/android-recycler-grid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/thetonrifles/recyclergrid/adapter/Adapter.java#L65) it is a sample project I made that shows this.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

When inflating layout for your views in adapter, you can set their height programmatically. In order to evaluate proper height to use you can rely on parent ViewGroup (that is the RecyclerView itself). Here it is a sample:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_item, parent, false);
    // work here if you need to control height of your items
    // keep in mind that parent is RecyclerView in this case
    int height = parent.getMeasuredHeight() / 4;
    itemView.setMinimumHeight(height);
    return new ItemViewHolder(itemView);        
}
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: Hello @thetonrifles, I tried your sample code already but looks like not help me in `(this case)`[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338627/set-height-gravity-of-span-item-in-gridlayoutmanager] that I don't know why. Please help me take a look. Thank you,

Comment: It seems that as of version recyclerview-v7:25.1.1 doesn't support or misbehave now. By invoking ```parent.getMeasuredHeight()``` the return value is always zero.

Comment: I just tested to ensure this and switched back as your project uses version 23.1.1 and now it works.

Comment: @drindt Thanks for raising this. I will take a look at this and provide an update to the answer!

Comment: Did you figure out a way to deal with this with the new recyclerview api? I'm getting 0 for `parent.getMeasuredHeight()` still

Comment: @clu Interesting... I tried but I didn't got the same issue. I can try again (since I was doing this some time ago). Of course feel free to share things that might look relevant in your implementation and that maybe I'm not considering right now.

Comment: why did you divide it by 4?

Answer (score 31):

As of support library 25.1.0, ABOVE ANSWER DOESN'T WORK. I suggest below modifications:

```
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams lp = (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = parent.getMeasuredHeight() / 4;
        v.setLayoutParams(lp);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
```

Comment: why divided by 4 ?

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi if the guy wants 4 row, divide by 6, if required 6 rows.

Comment: What if I need a different height for each row? I have posted a question but haven't been answered [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71277808/set-different-height-each-row-gridlayoutmanager-horizontal)

Answer (score 22):

You don't need to set the height of an item. The problem here is that image tries to fill all the space. Just add 
`android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your ImageView and it will not add blank spaces

Comment: Thank you, If someone needed to use `FrameLayout` for forground ripple effect on an `ImageView` in a `RecyclerView`, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 12):

Inside `onCreateViewHolder`, simply

```
v.getLayoutParams().width = parent.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
```

or

```
v.getLayoutParams().height = parent.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
```

Comment: pls add some more information to your answer like why it's correct or what differs to other answers

Comment: none of the above works for me, but this one does. tell what other information you need? do you want me to post full function here?

Comment: @PranavGoswami i just formated your answer not edited kindly check again

Answer (score 6):

**kotlin version**

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val binding = ItemBinding.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
        parent,
        false
    )
    binding.root.post {
        binding.root.layoutParams.height = parent.width/3
        binding.root.requestLayout()
    }
    return ViewHolder(binding)
}
```

here 3 is the span count of your `GridLayoutManager`
. You can replace  `binding.root` with your `itemView` , if you are not using Databinding

Answer (score 3):

sometime, getting size of inflate view in adapter return 0 or negative. another approach is get required size from out side the adapter, manipulate it and set it into view. in my case, another problem was size set effectless. so i set the size using layout parameter

here is setting my adapter in activity:

```
Display display = MainActivity.this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                    Point size = new Point();
                    display.getSize(size);
                    int  y = size.y;
                    y=(int)y/2;
 GridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this,2);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    NewOrderAdapter newOrderAdapter=new NewOrderAdapter(MainActivity.this,arrayListname,arrayListimage,y);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(newOrderAdapter);
```

and i set view size like this:

```
@Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.new_order_row, viewGroup, false);
        GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams params = (GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = ysize;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        myviewholder holder = new myviewholder(view);
        return holder;
    }
```

and dont forget to set a height to layout in your layout for initializatiin

Answer (score 3):

On a recent API Level currently 25 the height from the recycler in onCreateViewHolder
is always empty. This snippet is to set the hight after the recycler view's onMeasure
is invoked and set the correct height to the inflated list view.

```java
@Override
public DataBindingViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // You may inflate your view here.
    parent.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int height = parent.getMeasuredHeight() / rows;
            View view = holder.getBinding().getRoot();
            view.getLayoutParams().height = height;
        }
    });
    return holder;
}
```

Comment: nice solution, but 2 questions:
1) how can you be sure onMeasure was called when the runnable runs?
2) what is DataBindingViewHolder?

Answer (score 1):

This is my code for adjusting height of recycle view element based on actual aspect-ration required.

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) .inflate(R.layout.adapter_offers, parent, false);

    int width =  parent.getMeasuredWidth();
    float height = (float) width / Config.ASPECT_RATIO;//(Width/Height)
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) itemView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = Math.round(height);
    itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement which needed a dynamic height for each row in the grid with the ability to add and remove items from the RecyclerView as well. The problem with setting the height layout params in `onCreateViewHolder` as few of the answers suggests here, is that when an item is added/removed from the RecyclerView, the view is recycled and the `onCreateViewHolder` is not called again but rather a view within the pool is re-used (if available) and the layout manager would do a pass to calculate the height/width for the item and we would lose the original intended height/width set in the `onCreateViewHolder`.

This approach below might help who is facing a similar issue.

The key step here is to extend `GridLayoutManager` and override the following -

1. `generateDefaultLayoutParams`
2. `generateLayoutParams`
3. `checkLayoutParams`

The layout manager would looks something like this -

```
SpanGridLayoutManager : GridLayoutManager {

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int, defStyleRes: Int) :
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)

constructor(context: Context, spanCount: Int) : super(context, spanCount)
constructor(context: Context, spanCount: Int, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean) :
        super(context, spanCount, orientation, reverseLayout)

override fun generateDefaultLayoutParams(): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
    return spanLayoutSize(super.generateDefaultLayoutParams())
}

override fun generateLayoutParams(c: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
    return spanLayoutSize(super.generateLayoutParams(c, attrs))
}

override fun generateLayoutParams(lp: ViewGroup.LayoutParams): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
    return spanLayoutSize(super.generateLayoutParams(lp))
}

override fun checkLayoutParams(lp: RecyclerView.LayoutParams): Boolean {
    val layoutParams = generateDefaultLayoutParams()
    return super.checkLayoutParams(lp) &&
            layoutParams.width == lp.width &&
            layoutParams.height == lp.height
}

private fun spanLayoutSize(layoutParams: RecyclerView.LayoutParams): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
    layoutParams.height = if (some_condition) x else y
    return layoutParams
}
```

Here `x` and `y` can be the height in pixels that you would need to supply.