# Set height & gravity of Span item in GridLayoutManager

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm working with `Grid Layout Manager` in `Recycler View`.

I can :

- show one `View Group` inside `Grid Layout` like image below.
- Able to set `Space Item Decoration`
- Able to set different `Span Size Lookup`.

[image]

My issue is :

- Not able to set Height of each Span row inside, as 5 small circles in above image. (I want to set smaller height)
- The span item can not set gravity to center when it stay alone, as Big circle in above image

I tried to find method `setFullSize()` (exists when working with `StaggerGridLayoutManager`) in `GridLayoutManager` but looks like not useful.

People who know how to solve my issues,

Please tell me how to able do that,

Thank you,

p/s : Following coding show you :

`.xml`

```
<com.example.huy.customgridlayout.ScalingLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_item_"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/red_circle_256x256"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Topic"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/comment_mumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/topic"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="594"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/comment_mumber"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="Comments"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/comment"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="New! \n 2016/12/06 15:02"/>

</com.example.huy.customgridlayout.ScalingLayout>
```

`ScalingLayout.java`

```
public class ScalingLayout extends RelativeLayout {

private float scale = 1;

public ScalingLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

public ScalingLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ScalingLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public void setScale(float factor){
    scale = factor;
    invalidate();
}
public float getScale(){
    return scale;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.scale(scale, scale);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

}
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
private GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

private final String[] topics = new String[]{
        "Rain", // 1
        "Hot weather", // 2
        "Cold weather", // 3
        "Cool", // 4
        "Fall", // 5
        "Rain", // 1
        "Hot weather", // 2
        "Cold weather", // 3
        "Cool", // 4
        "Fall", // 5
        "Rain", // 1
        "Hot weather", // 2
        "Cold weather", // 3
        "Cool", // 4
        "Fall", // 5
        "Cool", // 4
        "Fall", // 5
};

private final int[] comment = new int[]{
        100, // 3
        200, // 4
        300, // 1
        400, // 5
        500, // 2
        600, // 6
        700, // 7
        1005, // 8
        290, // 9
        420, // 10
        20, // 11
        30, // 12
        40, // 13
        50, // 14
        60, // 15
        70, // 15
        80, // 15
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    int put = 5;

    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, put, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    SpacesItemDecoration decoration = new SpacesItemDecoration(-40);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);

    mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int pos) {

            // SET SPAN COLUMN IN HERE, RETURN ONE OF 5 COLUMNS I ALREADY SET IN ABOVE
            if (0 <= comment[pos] && comment[pos] < 150)
                return 1;
            else if (150 <= comment[pos] && comment[pos] < 300)
                return 2;
            else if (300 <= comment[pos] && comment[pos] < 450)
                return 3;
            else if (450 <= comment[pos] && comment[pos] < 600)
                return 4;
            else if (600 <= comment[pos])
                return 5;
            else return -1;

        }
    });

    ArrayList<Topic> mAa = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < comment.length; i++) {
        mAa.add(new Topic(comment[i], topics[i]));
    }

    GridLayoutAdapter adapter = new GridLayoutAdapter(this, mAa);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

`Adapter.java`

```
public class GridLayoutAdapter extends CustomRecyclerViewAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<Topic> topics;
//    private int screenWidth;

    public GridLayoutAdapter(Activity activity, List<Topic> images) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.topics = images;

//        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
//        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
//        Point size = new Point();
//        display.getSize(size);
//        screenWidth = size.x;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(activity)
                .inflate(R.layout.scaling_layout_item, parent, false);

        return new Holder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Holder myHolder = (Holder) holder;

        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(topics.get(position).getTopic(), opts);
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//        if (topics.get(position).getComment() < 100)
//            hideItemContent(myHolder);

        myHolder.mTvTopic.setText(topics.get(position).getTopic());
        myHolder.mTvCommentNumber.setText(String.valueOf(topics.get(position).getComment()));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return topics.size();
    }

    private void hideItemContent(Holder myHolder) {
        myHolder.mTvComment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.mTvCommentNumber.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.mTvDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        myHolder.mTvTopic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ScalingLayout mRl;

        private TextView mTvComment;
        private TextView mTvCommentNumber;
        private TextView mTvDate;
        private TextView mTvTopic;

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mRl = (ScalingLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_item_);

            mTvComment = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
            mTvCommentNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_mumber);
            mTvDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            mTvTopic = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.topic);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit losing myself on the criteria used for determining colspan. As far as I understood you want first item to fill the whole horizontal grid space, while the following items should fill one column each, right?

Comment: No, it's random. It depends on the range comments number I set so It can be filled respectively.

Comment: Ok, so basically your expectation is also to have some blank space beside an item in case the following one cannot fit the remaining space, right?

Comment: I want set small height to remove big blank space. Actually I know how to do that already. Still not push answer yet, set the height via LayoutParam inside `onBindViewHolder` of adapter should work.