# How to set spancount for recyclerview

Tags: java, android

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                                    android:id="@+id/rv46"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    app:spanCount="3"
                                    tools:listitem="@layout/wallet_items"

                                    />
```

I am implementing recyclerview with N number of items but i want to show only 3 item in list.Also i have set spancount for recyclerview but its not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple Android grid example using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager (like the old GridView)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the)

Comment: i am not using gridlayout

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Span count is used as part of a GridLayout to determine the number of items horizontally per row, hence the comment about GridLayoutManager.

Comment: It is not `GridLayout`. It is `RecyclerView` using `GridLayoutManager`. `RecyclerView` has a `layoutManager`. There are different types of `layoutManager` to choose from.  `GridLayoutManager` with a column count set to 3 suit your use case

Comment: I am using linearlayoutmanager

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. You may want to set the `height` of `itemView` to 1/3 of the parent view. You may refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221566/how-to-set-the-height-of-an-item-row-in-gridlayoutmanager) . This also applies to `LinearLayoutManager`.

Comment: You have to dynamically set the height/width also after undertaking the margin . thats the only way .

Answer (score 0):

instead of `app:spanCount="3"` use `tools:itemCount="3"`

Comment: This will only affect the preview, not the actual running of the app

Comment: then use adapter to set the limit by 'getItemCount()' method return 3 it  will return only 3 records on the view

Comment: i am using same adapter for different activity. i want to set item count 3 only for one activity

Comment: then while passing list to the adapter pass only 3 item

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class, assign a return value 3 of `getItemCount(), it shows only 3 list items

```
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
   return 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this condition in Your adapter `getItemCount()` method:

`return Math.min(yourlist.size(), 3);`

Like this:

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Math.min(memeberList.size(), 3);
    }
```